# Android Event contentResolver query synchronize problem

Tags: android, events, synchronization, android-contentresolver

I am using following code to pull the data from the core event calendar application to show in my app.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"),(new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected" }),null, null, null);
HashSet<String> calendarIds = new HashSet<String>();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  String _id = cursor.getString(0);
  String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
  Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");
  calendarIds.add(_id);
}

for (String id : calendarIds) {
                    Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(
                            "content://calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    ContentUris.appendId(builder, now
                            - ((DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) * 24));
                    ContentUris.appendId(builder, now
                            + ((DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) * 24));
                    Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                            new String[] { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay",
                                    "description", "eventLocation", "dtstart",
                                    "dtend", "eventStatus", "visibility",
                                    "transparency", "hasAlarm" },
                            "Calendars._id=" + id, null,
                            "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");
    while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    if (eventCursor != null) {
        String title = eventCursor.getString(0);
    }
}
```

The code is working fine. But sometime if I add a event in the calendar and come back to app, it is not showing the new event. If i exit the app and again come back or change the tab, the new event is added to the list. What have to do solve the synchronize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you come back to your app after the calendar add occurs, onResume() gets called.  Re-query the cursor there to cause your UI to update.

Also, you should look at the ContentObserver interface, which sets up a callback interface for being notified of changes (Say they show up on the device after a network sync while you haven't left your app at all.)

Finally, using a CursorAdapter to drive a ListView from your Cursor will set up a ContentObserver automatically and take care of a lot of the glue code you had to write to get this far.  It's a much more automatic way of doing it.